# Which of the following collections of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ form a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

1) $T_3 =\{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R}, [−a,a] : a \in \mathbb{R},a>0 \}$;

2) $T_4 = \{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R}, [−n,n], (−a,a) : a \in \mathbb{R}, a > 0, n \in \mathbb{N}^{>0} \}$.

I have that $T = \{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R}, (−a,a) : a \in \mathbb{R}, a>0 \}$ is a topology, but I am not sure how to continue with these 2.

To be a topology T must satisfy
(i) X and the empty set, Ø, belong to τ ,
(ii) the union of any (finite or infinite) number of sets in τ belongs to τ, and
(iii) the intersection of any two sets in τ belongs to τ

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what constitutes a topology (which properties you need to verify)?

Comment: (i) X and the empty set, Ø, belong to τ ,
(ii) the union of any (finite or infinite) number of sets in τ belongs to τ, and
(iii) the intersection of any two sets in τ belongs to τ

Comment: Perfect (add that to the question; I believe it'll help draw in answers). Now, where you able to prove (ii) or (iii) for any collection (I presume you haven't disproved either of them, otherwise you'd have your answer)?

Comment: so far, only using a counter example so I haven't proved (ii) or (iii) only disproved!

Comment: For the second one, distinguish the cases when a union has infinitely many sets of the form $[-n,n]$, and the case it doesn't

Comment: @StefanHamcke I don't understand the hint, sorry :(

Comment: I wanted to say: In the union of open sets you can have either infinitely many sets of the form $[-n,n]$ for natural $n$, in which case the union is $??$ no matter how many $(-a,a)$-sets there are. In the other case, there are only a finite number of $[-n,n]$-sets, but the union will still be an open set.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

1. Property (iii) is fairly simple to prove in both $T_3,T_4$, so one should concentrate on property (ii) in both.
2. With that in mind, given $\{a_\lambda : \lambda\in\Lambda\}\subset\Bbb R_+$, can you find $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}(-a_\lambda,a_\lambda)$? Can you find $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}[-a_\lambda,a_\lambda]$?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the blunder earlier. Hope this is correct.

Say $A = (0, 10)$ Then, $ \bigcup_{a\in A} [-a, a] = (-10, 10) \not \in T_3$. Therefore, $T_3$ is not closed under arbitrary unions and hence does not form a Topology.

Now to $T_4$. Consider $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{1\} } ( - \frac  2 3 + \frac 1 n, \frac 2 3  - \frac 1 n) $ which is equal to $[- \frac  2 3,  \frac  2 3]$ which is not an element of $T_4$.

Therefore both sets do not qualify to be a Topology.

Comment: that union does not contain the point $2/3$.

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke: You're right.. It's $( - \frac 2 3, \frac 2 3)$ Can't believe I screwed up again. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: I would just edit it. You are right at least for $T_3$, that it is not a topology. I'm pretty sure $T_4$ is a topology.

Comment: Not to impose my system on anyone, but perhaps leave that for OP to figure out, based on what you did with $T_3$? I won't revise my answer now that you posted this.